# How to convert string array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string array that holds the value in this fashion .
[vi , 26 , new york , retired] [ji, 27 , manhattan , retired] [ti, 28 , manhattan , working] and so on

I converted string array to Array list and i gave `arr.get(1)` which is giving me the value `26` , `27` , `28` so on.

I want to iterate the fields in a fashion it should take vi , 26 , new york , retired in the 1st iteration , ji, 27 , manhattan , retired in the 2nd iteration and so on. So i can get the value based on index for each iteration. Let's say `arr.get(0)` gives me vi , `arr.get(1)` gives me 27 n so on

where count is the number of lines in the file which is 3 in this example and the file was initially pipe separated

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int  len = arr.get(i).length();
    String[] s = arr.get(i).toString().split("\\|");
    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(s);
    System.out.println(wordList.get(1));
}
```

when i gave `wordList.get(1)` . i m getting the output 26,27,28

Comment: Can you post a specific code example?

Comment: `arr[0][1]` this will return the 2nd element from the first sub array..

Comment: Can you please explain your question clearly.

Comment: I have added the code snippet above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are iterating through each string array and updating the `s` variable each time. Then you are outputting that specific index of the original `arr` (is this an ArrayList?). I recommend you create a variable that holds Lists objects outside the loop:

```
     List<List<String>> container;

     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
      {
        int  len = arr.get(i).length();
        String[] s = arr.get(i).toString().split("\\|");
        List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(s);
        container.add(wordList);
       }
```

Then you can get each object from this List of Lists object:

```
container.get(0).get(1) //would return only 26.
```

This is assuming there isn't something else wrong with your code. I feel like not all of the code is presented though. The methodology would be the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting multiple outputs because you're printing the second element in the list for each of your three iterations. Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
List<String>[] wordListArray = new List<String>[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int  len = arr.get(i).length();
            String[] s = arr.get(i).toString().split("\\|");
            List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(s);
            wordListArray[i] = wordList;
System.out.println(wordListArray[0].get(1)); //where zero returns the first word list (which has 26)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you convert your String Array to Array List. Then you can find the element by index. Please refer below code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BookFine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1[]=new String[]{"vi" , "26" , "new york" , "retired"}; 
        String s2[]=new String[]{"ji", "27" , "manhattan" , "retired"}; 
        String s3[]=new String[]{"ti", "28" , "manhattan" , "working"};

        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(wordList, s1);
        Collections.addAll(wordList, s2);
        Collections.addAll(wordList, s3);

        System.out.println(wordList.get(1));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by building custom objects and overriding its `toString()` method

1.Build the custom object class and override its `toString()` method as follow:

```
public class ComplexObject{
    private String col1;
    private int col2;
    private String col3;
    private String col4;



    public ComplexObject(String x, int w, String y, String z)
    {
        this.col1 = x;
        this.col2 = w;
        this.col3 = y;
        this.col4 = z;
    }

    //Be sure to override the toString() method because this override is responsible to show your interested values
    public String toString()
    {
        return  Integer.toString(this.col2);
    }
 }
```

2. Use ArrayList to add object of that class, here I have tested it for you:

   public class TestClass
           {
           public static void main(String[] ){

   ```
           ArrayList<ComplexObject> arr = new ArrayList<ComplexObject>();



           arr.add(new ComplexObject("vi", 26, "new york", "retired"));
           arr.add(new ComplexObject("ji", 27, "manhatan", "retired"));
           arr.add(new ComplexObject("ti", 28, "manhatan", "retired"));



           for(int i =0; i<arr.size(); i++)
           {
               System.out.println(arr.get(i));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

it gives you **26 27 28** as a result